# rpmbuild complains about dependencies that are there

Tags: linux, build, dependencies, rpmbuild

Trying to build my own monit RPM package on SLES12 SP5 using `rpmbuild`, I got some error that confuses me:

```shell
> rpmbuild -ba -r ~/rpmbuild GNU/RPM/monit.spec
error: Failed build dependencies:
        flex >= 2.6 is needed by monit-12:5.29.0-0.0.x86_64
        bison >= 2.7 is needed by monit-12:5.29.0-0.0.x86_64
        libopenssl-devel >= 1.0.2p is needed by monit-12:5.29.0-0.0.x86_64
        pam-devel >= 1.1.8 is needed by monit-12:5.29.0-0.0.x86_64
> rpm -q flex bison libopenssl-devel pam-devel
flex-2.6.4-9.7.1.x86_64
bison-2.7-6.107.x86_64
libopenssl-devel-1.0.2p-1.13.noarch
pam-devel-1.1.8-24.49.1.x86_64
```

It looks as if all dependencies are there, but still `rpmbuild` complains!

Don't I see the obvious, or is there something broken in `rpmbuild`?
The package providing `rpmbuild` is `rpm-build-4.11.2-16.21.1.x86_64` (latest as of today).

### Additional Info

It seems there's something broken in `rpmbuild`, because when adding `--nodeps` the compilation succeeds, but I noticed that the specified "buildroot" is duplicated, i.e.: it uses "~/rpmbuild/~/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT" when packaging, but the correct "BUILD" directory when compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly it seems the missing dependencies were triggered by option `-r ~/rpmbuild`; leaving it out made the build succeed, and it was using `$HOME/rpmbuild` as root directory anyway.